# Is WCF considered Socket Programming? Does WCF even use sockets but abstract them from the user?

Tags: wcf, sockets

Does WCF use sockets but abstract them from the user?

Or does not not use sockets at any level?

Comment: nope. you can compare WCF with a JSON API

Comment: So you have WCF experience but are applying for a job where they ask for socket experience?

Comment: no no, not job related, I was just wondering

Comment: More reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59456579/is-wcf-built-on-sockets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short of rococo games involving network drivers (e.g. WinPCap), *ALL* network access on Windows uses sockets at some level.